# Python Program Giving me StopIteration

Tags: python, compiler-errors, generator

I have made a function: generatesequence (shown below)

```
def generatesequence(start: float, itera: float = 1, stop: float = None):
    """
    Generate a sequence, that can have a stopping point, starting point.
    """

    __num = start

    # if sequence has a stopping point
    if stop != None:
        # if stop is negative
        if stop < 0:
           # while num is greater than stop (0 < 5, but 0 > -5)
            while __num >= stop:
                # yield __num variable (yield = return without exiting function)
                yield __num
                # add iter to __num
                __num += itera

        else:
            while __num <= stop:
                yield __num
                __num += itera
    else:
        # if sequence has no stopping point, run forever
        while True:
            yield __num
            __num += itera
```

I have also made a Sequence Class (also shown below)

```
class Sequence:
  def __init__(self, start, itera, stop):
    self.sequence = generatesequence(start, itera, stop)
    self.sequencelength = iterlen(self.sequence)
    print(self.sequencelength)

 def printself(self):
    for i in range(self.sequencelength):
      print(next(self.sequence))
```

However, when I run printself on a Sequence instance, it gives me a StopIteration error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of For i in range(self.sequencelength), use for i in self.sequence

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that with a generator, you can just do the following:

```py
 def printself(self):
    for i in self.sequence:
      print(i)
```

This way you don't need to calculate the length of the generator beforehand

Comment: I have copy-pasted the new function into my class, and it won't print anything

Answer (score 0):

Caculating length of generator defies the whole purpose of using generator. And it also explains StopIteration.

Unlike list or some data structure that takes O(n) memory space, generator takes O(1) space and it cannot know the length without iterating one by one.

And by calcuating length you have moved the iter for your generator from start to end, and now your iter points at StopIteration.

Now when you access generator afterwards it returns StopIteration.

Actually the whole purpose of generator and the likes is to save memory space for iterables that you know will be iterated at most once. You can not do two or more full iterations on generator. To do that, use list function on generator beforehand and save values in list or similar data structures . Or simply recreate generator after it's been used up (=iterated over).

In short, to fix bug, remove the line where it computes length of generator in init method. And do for loop using

"for i in generator_name: "

syntax

Alternatively you can make a method that makes generator and call it to recreate generator whenever / whereever you need